# re-hydrating tweets / extracting data from partial stream

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, tweepy

I have a spark stream I am getting from Kafka (tweets ids) and I am trying to re-hydrate adittional data using tweepy\twarc\twython while streaming.
I tried to extract the ids column from the streaming DataFrame, so I'll be able to iterate over it (could not find a way to iterate the stream directly) and look up the additional data using tweepy.

tried the following:

```
ids= []
def process_row(row,ids):
    ids.append(row.tweet_id) 
query = FlattenedDF.writeStream.foreach(process_row).start()
```

I also tried to convert it directly:

```
ids = FlattenedDF.select('tweet_id').collect()
```

got the error : "Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start"

is there any better way to do it?
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to follow the hint given in the error message by adding a `query.start` at the end of your code? (Sorry, I am not completely familiar with the python syntax, but feel free to research on the `start` and `awaitTermination` methods for spark streaming.)

Comment: tried both, did not work..

Comment: then you might want to share more of your code to get the full picture.